# Multiple data tables involved on one form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

Updated 08/14/2012 12:05pm
I will try to explain my situation and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a form in my project that will have several tables involved all of the tables are already set up with relationships. Here are the models that are related.

```
namespace QQAForm.Models
 {
  public class AuditSchedule
    {
    public virtual int AuditScheduleID { get; set; }
    public virtual Nullable<DateTime> audit_completed_date { get; set; }
    public virtual string gl_cmp_key { get; set; }
    public virtual string audit_year { get; set; }
    public virtual string ar_ship_key { get; set; }
    public virtual string ar_ship_name { get; set; }
    public virtual string im_adres_city { get; set; }
    public virtual string im_adres_state { get; set; }
    public virtual string audit_type { get; set; }
    public virtual string audit_no { get; set; }
    public virtual string audit_group { get; set; }
    public virtual string Footage { get; set; }
    public virtual string Rolling3MosFootage { get; set; }
    public virtual string snp_SalesRep8 { get; set; }
    public virtual string epg_sales_rep_accountable { get; set; }
    public virtual string tech_service_rep { get; set; }
    public virtual string audit_done_by { get; set; }
    public virtual Nullable<DateTime> audit_recieved_date { get; set; }
    public virtual string audit_notes { get; set; }
    public virtual string audit_pdf { get; set; }
    public virtual string updated { get; set; }
    public virtual string hidden { get; set; }
    public virtual string en_stats_key { get; set; }
    public virtual string Control_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Nullable<DateTime> audit_date { get; set; }
    public virtual string contacts_present { get; set; }
    public virtual string audit_furnished_to { get; set; }
    public virtual string spacer_type { get; set; }



   }
}
```

MainQuestion:

```
namespace QQAForm.Models
{
public class MainQuestion
    {
    public virtual int MainQuestionID { get; set; }
    public virtual int SubCategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual int ReferenceNo { get; set; }
    public virtual int DisplayIndex { get; set; }
    public virtual int SuggestionID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question { get; set; }

    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Suggestion> suggestions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DocumentLink> documentLink { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Child Questions:

```
namespace QQAForm.Models
{
public class ChildQuestion
    {
    public virtual int ChildQuestionID { get; set; }
    public virtual int MainQuestionID { get; set; }
    public virtual int ReferenceNo { get; set; }
    public virtual int DisplayIndex { get; set; }
    public virtual string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserEntityType { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserEntityTexts { get; set; }

    public virtual MainQuestion MainQuestion { get; set; }



    }
 }
```

Suggestions:

```
namespace QQAForm.Models
{
public class Suggestion
    {
    public virtual int SuggestionID { get; set; }
    public virtual int MainQuestionID { get; set; }
    public virtual int DisplayIndex { get; set; }
    public virtual string ReferenceNo { get; set; }
    public virtual string Suggestions { get; set; }

    public virtual MainQuestion MainQuestion { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Main Answer:

```
namespace QQAForm.Models
{
public class MainAnswer
    {
    public virtual int MainAnswerID { get; set; }
    public virtual int AuditScheduleID { get; set; }
    public virtual int MainQuestionID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Score { get; set; }
    public virtual string AdditionalNotes { get; set; }

    public virtual AuditSchedule AuditSchedule { get; set; }
    public virtual MainQuestion MainQuestion { get; set; }

    }
 }
```

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to display a question from one table that has a relationship with another table with sub questions and check boxes for the answer. The answers are simple Yes, No, and N/A. They are also held in a different table. The reason i have all of this in data tables is they have to be editable or if i want to add to the areas.
 This is what the page should look like. i have incerted text to give the look for the page.

Layout:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="head" class="container">
    @Html.Partial("Header")
 </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="main">
            <ul id="breadcrumbs">

            </ul>
            <div id="formTopCol">
              @RenderBody()
              @*@Html.Partial("_Audit")*@  
            </div>
            <div id="formBottomCol">
                    @Html.Action("_SubCategory")

                <div id="formBottomRightCol">
                    @Html.Action("_Forms")
                    @*@RenderBody()*@
                </div>
                <div style="clear:left;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="container">
       @Html.Partial("Footer")
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

I have set up in the global.asax a string to accept a audit record and then pull the main question. there is a side menu that will select the question area's. This is done in a view where the Audit schedule is the Body and the side menu and form question/answers are Html.Action() for partials.

Global Code:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "AuditSchedule", // Route name

            "AuditSchedule/Audit/{id}/{section}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "AuditSchedule", action = "Audit", id = UrlParameter.Optional, section = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults

        );
```

I have tried to play around with a view model for this but i cannot get this to work. When it comes to databases in C# coding i am really weak.

Here is the Model i am working on with the controller:

```
namespace QQAForm.ViewModels
{
public class AuditFormEdit
{
    public Models.MainAnswer ScoreInstance { get; set; }

    public List<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper> ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList { get; set; }

    public void InitializeScoreCheckBoxHelperList(List<Models.Score> ScoreList)
    {
        if (this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList == null)
            this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList = new List<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper>();

        if (ScoreList != null
            && this.ScoreInstance != null)
        {
            this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Clear();
            ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper scoreCardCheckBoxHelper;
            string scoreTypes =
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ScoreInstance.Score) ?
                string.Empty : this.ScoreInstance.Score;
            foreach (Models.Score scoreType in ScoreList)
            {
                scoreCardCheckBoxHelper = new ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper(scoreType);
                if (scoreTypes.Contains(scoreType.ScoreName))
                    scoreCardCheckBoxHelper.Checked = true;
                this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Add(scoreCardCheckBoxHelper);
            }
        }
    }

    public void PopulateCheckBoxsToScores()
    {
        this.ScoreInstance.Score = string.Empty;
        var scoreType = this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Where(x => x.Checked)
                              .Select<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper, string>(x => x.ScoreName)
                              .AsEnumerable();
        this.ScoreInstance.Score = string.Join(", ", scoreType);
    }


    public class ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper : Models.Score
    {
        public bool Checked { get; set; }

        public ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper() : base() { }

        public ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper(Models.Score scoreCard)
        {
            this.ScoreID = scoreCard.ScoreID;
            this.ScoreName = scoreCard.ScoreName;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Controller section:

```
        //get
    public ActionResult _Forms(int id)
    {
        AuditFormEdit viewModel = new AuditFormEdit();
        //viewModel.ScoreInstance = _db.MainAnswers.Single(r => r.AuditScheduleID == id);
        viewModel.InitializeScoreCheckBoxHelperList(_db.Scores.ToList());
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    //post
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _Forms(int id, AuditFormEdit viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.PopulateCheckBoxsToScores();
            _db.Entry(viewModel.ScoreInstance).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("/");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

As i stated before the ViewModel does not work because i am asking for an id that does not exist. Right now the view model only has code to populate check boxes for the answers.

Added view codes 08/14/2012 1:00pm

Form partial view mostly test but script that compliments the check box code

```
@{ Layout = null; }
@model QQAForm.ViewModels.AuditFormEdit

<table width="698" border="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td align="center"><b>Section</b><br />1.0</td>
<td><b>Glass edge damage noted. (shells, flakes, sharks teeth)</b>
<br /><br />

@Html.CheckBox("suggestion1") &nbsp;
It was noted that there was a significant amount of glass edge damage observed on the  IG units being produced.  
This glass edge damage may lead to a significantly high glass breakage rate in IG unit handling, in the glazing operation and in service.
[MAJOR CONCERN]
The cause of this glass edge damage should be determined and efforts made to eliminate the damage. 
<br /><br />
@Html.CheckBox("suggestion2") &nbsp;
The glass edge should be smooth and free of chips, flakes, wings, or other damage. Damaged edges may result in stress cracks or premature IG unit failure.
[MAJOR CONCERN]
<br /><br />

<label>Additional Notes:</label><br />
@Html.TextArea("Additional Notes")
<br />
</td>
<td>
        @for (int index = 0; index < Model.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Count; index++)
        {

            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index].Checked)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index], Model.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index].ScoreName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index].ScoreID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index].ScoreName)


        }

 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the side menu partial:

```
@{ Layout = null; }

@model IEnumerable<QQAForm.Models.SubCategory>
<div id="menuCol">
<h3>Audit Sections</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>

      @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

                <div class="sidemenu">
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.SubcategoryName, "Audit", new { section = item.SubCategoryID }, null)
                </div>

        }
            </li>
        </ul>   
</div>
```

This is the Body:

```
@model QQAForm.Models.AuditSchedule
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
Layout = "~/Views/AuditSchedule/_FormLayout.cshtml";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"    type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
<table class="audit-display">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Customer</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>EPG TSM Rep/NAM</th>
<th>EPG RSM (or NAM's VP)</th>
<th>Tech Rep</th>
<th>Audit Type</th>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AuditScheduleID)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ar_ship_name)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.im_adres_city)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.im_adres_state)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.epg_sales_rep_accountable)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.snp_SalesRep8)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.tech_service_rep)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.audit_type)</td>


</tr>
 </table>
 <table class="audit-display">
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Contacts Present</th>
<th>Audit Furnished To</th>
<th>Audit Done By (If not sheduled)</th>
<th>Spacer's Used</th>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.audit_date)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.contacts_present)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.audit_furnished_to)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.audit_done_by)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.spacer_type)</td>

</tr>
</table>

</fieldset>
<hr />

}
```

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Try to be more concise, add paragraph, indentation, code samples...

Comment: I have added all the associated code to the question.

Comment: is there an exception being thrown?

Comment: Sorry, but it is even worse now. My first advice was : be concise...

Comment: bottom line is i need to know how to show a question from a table and have the check boxes populated for the scores all the input will go into a different table that is related to the customer. So when i select the customer i can view an array of answers for the questions. i am stuck in my view model and i am not sure that the link i used in the global.asax is correct either. it needs to put the id of the question and the customer from AuditSchedule in the table so that it can be viewed later. currently i cannot get the checkboxes to show up.

Comment: So the checkboxes are showing up in the UI, but when you try to save them you don't know the best way to do that? Or because the ID is not available you can't save them?

Comment: Checkboxes do not even show up at all. getting them to save is the next challenge. This same code works in another part of the site - but i am saving it to the same table just pulling the text from another table. this is different it needs to save it to a different table as well as show the check boxes

Answer (score 0):

why are you adding an `int id` parameter to _Forms HttpPost action?  You don't use it so you don't need it then, right?  You also don't demonstrate your view code.

Comment: This could have been a comment.

Comment: he said his problem is that he's asking for an id that doesn't exist.  I don't see why he needs it, so it can be removed, thus fixing his problem.  I can delete this answer and make it a comment.

Comment: Yes that would be correct. You can see that it is commented out. it still does not produce the checkboxes. I think it is because the way it is written it is looking for the ID so it knows where to put the text. in this case it would be the answers and that will not have an id until it is submitted.

Comment: I need the ID so i can select the right section that has the question. so the ID would be used in the link when a side menu button is selected it will bring up that question. while still maintaing the id for the auditschedule. /AuditSchedule/Audit/1192/1 would be audit schedule 1192 and question 1.